# How does a kernel module gets attached to a running kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am a learing device drivers. So far I've executed small modules. I was wondering how linux allows insertion of a module even while its running? I did a search for it but not satisfied or may be could not understand. All I got is linux daemon executes modprobe add new module. But my question is how this happen? The kernel is in execution already. How does the new executable file gets attached to the running kernel? 
Thanks.

Comment: You may find [this manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/init_module.2.html) of some help.

Answer (score 4):

A kernel module is really just an object file (or, in other words, a half linked program) with exposed functions.

`modprobe` uses a special system call to load the module into the kernel. After that, the kernel has a built in linker that finishes linking the object file to the running kernel. The built in linker knows the addresses of all the kernel functions beforehand so it knows how to fill the blanks.

After that, the kernel jumps to the entry point of the kernel module and the module does its work. From then on, the module is basically part of the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

modprobe is a great program to add modules to the kernel. You may get a basic idea bout modprobe and its working from the following links.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/init_module.2.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modprobe